# How to change multiple variables, not values, using an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

This is a very silly question, and maybe I'm just blanking on this right now. How can I change several variables at once? Let's say I have this:

```
var bob = "bob"
var joe = "joe"

var arr = [bob, joe]
arr[1] = "joseph"

print(joe)

// this returns "joe" and not sarah, because what happened is, arr is now equal to [bob, sarah]
```

How can I make it so that I modify arr, and the actual "joe" variable is changed? Not just the array values?

Very silly question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You have to involve a reference type to make this work, because Swift's `String` and `Array` are value types. For example, you could use `NSMutableString` like this:

```
import Foundation

let bob: NSMutableString = "bob"
let joe: NSMutableString = "joe"

let arr = [bob, joe]

arr[1].setString("joseph")
print(joe)

// Output: joseph
```

However, [five whys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys) might be more appropriate here.